# I would like to edit the filemanager sidebar, not the OS sidebar. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: configuration, filemanager, default

I would like to remove the Music, Video, and Public folders from the default folders that display when you open a folder using filemanager with the sidebar visible. In other words, I have bookmarks that I would like to access with one click but the filemanager window is not tall enough to display them all. Removing these default folders (which I never use) and which are stacked on top of my bookmarks would allow more room for my bookmarks to display. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Edit your config file: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks `

Comment: Thank you for the response. Those permanent bookmarks are not listed in that file. Any other suggestions? Possibly a different file? Also I don't think those permanent bookmarks are referred to as "bookmarks" in the OS. I think bookmarks only refers to those that are user created.

Comment: The links I want to delete are to the permanent OS folders Music, Videos, Documents, etc. deleting the actual folders does nothing but give me an error. They still display on the sidebar of the folder window.